# IIS 6.1 periodically breaks so as to be unstartable

Tags: c#, iis-6

I have a strange issue that occurs every day. I have recently been given a fellow developers laptop with Windows7 & IIS6 (they've left) and my previous laptop (WidnowsXP & IIS 5) has been recycled into the system, so I'm stuck with this one and didn't originally set up the system. Developing worked fine on my old computer, but on this one.

I am developing an ASP.NET website and after a while of editing, building, then going to localhost in IE, the page doesn't show. The process w3wp.exe isn't in my list of processes in the task manager. If I call iisreset.exe, this usually fixes it at first (i.e. going to localhost starts w3wp.exe and after a short while my page appears).

After a few runs of this, even this fix doesn't work, but I've found that if I close IE, then run iisreset.exe it fixes it.

Then after a few runs of this, I also have to close Visual Studio & IE, then iisreset.exe. Once I get to this stage, I can't make a single edit in visual studio without having to close it to run the web page. Note, I'm not running in debug mode. I've even tried editing in notepad++ for simple edits and I have to close that too before iisreset works!

Eventually I end up restarting my computer because these incantations stop working. I'm at the end of my tether. Does anyone know what could actually be wrong or where I should start looking for a real fix?

Comment: It sounds like you might be having some unhandled (or unhandleable) exceptions in your code, and your IIS and Application pools aren't configured to auto-restart on failure. Maybe. Seriously, Windows 98? :D Have you considered using IIS Express? It's a stand-alone development IIS, basically. Oh, and you  probably aren't used to working with windows users - IIS is most likely running under a different account, so you need to show processes of all users in task manager (which needs administrator permissions). The process is called "IIS Worker Process".

Comment: Oops, my fingers ran away with me. I meant I was running WindowsXP. I've corrected my post.The reason IIS6 is on here is to match our live environment, which is running fine.

Comment: Well, try looking in the event log (using event viewer). It will probably have some information about the reasons IIS is failing (maybe even the .NET exception if that's the cause).

Comment: Just to be clear, IIS is working fine, my page is working fine. I can change the smallest piece of plain text on an aspx page (no code edits, no recompile needed) then when I next go to my page, if fails. I'm not adding any code or doing anything different when I come back to IE, I'm just opening a page that I've been opening all day.

Comment: Well, it will need some time to recompile the application. Are you sure you're not just being impatient? And of course, you will lose `Session` etc. when the recompile happens. You don't need to do a recompile in Visual Studio, changing any file might (the rules aren't all that simple) cause the application pool to recycle and rebuild the web site. But apart from losing process memory, it should become available when that's done. What does IIS Manager show? It's much more useful on IIS 6 than it was on IIS 5, you should use that :)

Comment: If you change anything slightly major, yes, it sometimes needs time to compile, but you still see w3wp.exe process appear straight away. But changing a bit of text doesn't require a recompile. And I have left it trying to run over lunchtime so it's not an impatience issue. Plus it works first thing every morning for 20, 30, 40 edits/runs so I'm used to how long it takes. What should IISManager show? Whereabouts would I look in it to find something useful to my problem?

Comment: Interesting. You can look at whether the IIS server itself is running, and at the status of the application pools. Look at the recycling settings of the application pool. Did you have a look at event viewer? You might also want to enable process orphaning for the debugging - instead of killing `w3wp` when it becomes unresponsive, it will just abandon it, so you can attach a debugger and check where it's stuck - if it's actually stuck. Disabling overlapped recycling might also help somewhat, if your application doesn't handle multi-instancing well. Gather data :)

Comment: Thanks for your interest so far @Luaan. I'll gather some data today (once it breaks) and see where that leads me.